# App Crashes With editText

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-activity, double

im pretty new at this whole java/android coding so i was seeking help from the more experienced. Would you happen to know why my app keeps crashing when i hit back space for the editText tag. I believe its because of the double and when the content goes to backspaces it enters a null, however ive been looking around for a if statement to enter and make it so that its okay if its empty. The xml sheet with the edit/text view is basic with the tags just so you know. If anyone knows how i can make it not crash i would appreciate it :) Thanks

```
package xxxx.xxxx.xxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TemperatureActivity extends Activity {
    EditText input;
    TextView output;
    String afterTextChanged = "";
    String beforeTextChanged = "";
    String onTextChanged = "";

        //    MainActivity instance = new MainActivity();
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.temperature_layout);
//            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TemperatureInput);
            output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CelsiusOutput);
            input.addTextChangedListener(watch);

        }

        public TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                onTextChanged = input.getText().toString();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                beforeTextChanged = input.getText().toString();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int a, int b, int c) {
                afterTextChanged = input.getText().toString();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Parsing String to double
                double cercuils = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                double faherenheit = cercuils * 9 / 5 + 32;

                if (input == null) {
                    output.setText("ERROR");
                }



                output.setText(faherenheit + "");
                if (a == 9) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Maximum Limit Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }
//}

// Formula for C to F
//°C  x  9/5 + 32 = °F

// Formula for f to c
//37°C x  9/5 + 32 = 98.6°F
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line

```
double cercuils = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
```

you parse a `String` to a `Double` value. but maybe your `String` not be a number or it be empty.
you can use `try catch` to if it is number parse it.

```
 double cercuils=0;
            try {
                 cercuils = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                 cercuils = 0;
            }
```

and use

```
if(cercuils ==0)
{
output.setText("Please enter a number");
}else{
output.setText(faherenheit + "");
}
```

instead of

```
output.setText(faherenheit + "");
```

Comment: So now the code for cercuils is comming up as an error as never used 'Double faherenheit = cercuils * 9 / 5 + 32;' cercuils says cannot resolve symbol "cercuils"

Comment: @ Hamidreza the error changed to - variable 'cercuils' might not have been initilized

Comment: It works but i cant have cercuils be 0 when empty, its a converting program im making so if nothing is entered it will be converted to 32 as the code is cercuils * 9 / 5 + 32; or 0 * (9/5) + 32 = 32. is there any way to make nothing show up and still not crash?

Comment: yes. codes in `catch` block will run when codes in `try` block cant run. you can use it. or you can  check `if (cercuils != 0)` then `cercuils * 9 / 5 + 32;` or show `Toast`. it is play with codes

Answer (score 0):

**You have to insert the decimal point with "0" , not just "." . Or you can solve this programmatically by adding "0" also. Update your code as follows ,**

```
num2 = Double.parseDouble("0" + editText2.getText().toString());
```